# How to start writing text on upper right side of image in html?

Tags: html, html-table

I have create an html page you can check it [here](http://emu.nausal.com/Page5.htm)

I want that the text start from upper right cornet of image and then go on you can see this example click [here](http://alpacafarmingguide.com/howmany.htm). I want exact style like this.

Any idea please; I am waiting.

Comment: are you talking about header part

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `<table>` element and use the CSS [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp) property:

```
<img style="height: 96px; width: 135px; float: left;" />
Young chicks need to be cared for in better facilities than adults, etc., etc.
```